# How to declare a variable in python without assigning a value?

Tags: python, iteration, fractals, mandelbrot

I'm trying to create graphs of the Mandelbrot set.

I have managed to do this by iterating over a lot of points but this takes a lot of processing power, so I'm now trying to generate a polynomial by iterating `f(z) = z**2 + c` many times and then finding the roots for `z = c`, in order to generate a boundary of the set.

However I can't seem to get Python to generate the polynomial, any help would be much apprecaited.

Edit:Implemented azro's fix but now I get the error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'

Code so far:

```
import numpy as np

c = None

def f(z):
    return z**2 + c

eqn = c

for i in range(100):
    eqn = f(eqn)

np.roots(eqn)
```

Comment: `return z**2 + c`

Comment: You should rename your question, cause when I saw it, I wanted to suggest `c = None`

Comment: Good catch, but now i get this error:   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations; only assignments.

Comment: Even if you were to declare `c` without assigning a value, you'd just get a `NameError` from trying to use a variable with no value. You've picked a non-solution for your underlying problem.

Comment: Your `c = None` so your `eqn` will be `None` too, when you call f(eqn) you are trying `None**2`! (I removed a wrong suggestion)

Comment: @LeventeSimofi: That would do a thing completely different from what olibpool is trying to do; the result would have nothing to do with the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: @LeventeSimofi wouldn't f(i) apply the function to each i in the range(300)? I want to apply f succesive times to the inital value of c. In mathematical terms: f^100(c)

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `c = 0` instead since it's a numeric calculation? I'm not sure what you're planning to do with `np.roots` though that part is unclear to me.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica do you have a better title that I could use? I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: @r.ook nah I need c to be a variable so that I can solve it like you would for a polynomial. For example: c^3 + c^2 + c = 0

Comment: @olibpool sorry for my bad, I did not implemented Mandlebrot sets before. I just took a look at the code and knowing the error suggested something. I think that `np.roots(eqn)` need to be in the loop and he needs to give an initial value for `eqn`. Is that right?

Comment: `c` is a *name* to an object, which currently will be assigned to `0` based on my suggestion (or `None` in your case).  I'm not familiar with the Mandelbrot set but if `c` needs to be changed during each loop, you just need to reassign it in your loops. e.g. `c = some_new_value`

Comment: From the [numpy roots documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html), it looks like the input should be the coefficients of the poynomial. So couldn't you just generate an array with the coefficients to pass to `np.roots`?

Comment: @LeventeSimofi I don't think so, as I only want to find the roots at the end, after I've generated the polynomial

Comment: @r.ook c cannot be defined as a value until the end when I need to solve the resulting polynomial, it needs to be able to be used to generate values of c that can be used to graph the boundary of the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: @gnodab This looks like the solution! Thanks man, now I just need to work out how to generate the coefficients of the polynomail haha

Comment: @olibpool No problem. I still am not sure if it is possible though. I can plot the mandelbrot function using standard iterations (doesn't seem too hard on processing for me). But I'm not sure you can generate the coefficients of the polynomial (since it depends on `C`). Then the root function may be super slow anyway.

Comment: @gnodab It might just be that my code is very inefficient (or my computer is slow) but I was looking on [this website](http://renatofonseca.net/mandelbrotset.php) and it seems like they were able to solve the polynomial so I wanted to see if I could do it. I'm fairly certain it would be possible to do in Mathematica but I've not tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very hard problem. Searching through literature, I only found [this](http://cosinekitty.com/mandel_poly.html) (which doesn't seem very reputable). However, it does seem to begin to create what you want. This is only up to 8 iterations. So the polynomial gets very complicated very fast. See the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coeff = [0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 26, 44, 69, 94, 114, 116, 94, 60, 28, 8, 1]
coeff = [0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1302, 3774, 10652, 29538, 80812, 218324, 582408, 1534301, 3993030, 10269590, 26108844, 65626918, 163107044, 400844588, 974083128, 2340595778, 5560968284, 13062923500, 30336029592, 69640352964, 158015533208, 354347339496, 785248461712, 1719477330477, 3720187393990, 7952125694214, 16792863663700, 35031835376454, 72188854953372, 146932182777116, 295372837865192, 586400982013486, 1149605839249820, 2225301467579844, 4252710138415640, 8022825031835276, 14938862548001560, 27452211062573400, 49778848242964944, 89054473147697354, 157160523515654628, 273551721580800380, 469540646039042536, 794643418760272876, 1325752376790240280, 2180053774442766712, 3532711259225506384, 5640327912922026260, 8870996681171366696, 13741246529612440920, 20959276151880728336, 31472438318100876584, 46514944583399578896, 67649247253332557392, 96791719611591962592, 136210493669590627493, 188481251186354006062, 256386228250001079082, 342743629811082484420, 450159936955994386738, 580706779030058464252, 735537050036491961156, 914470757914434625800, 1115597581733327913554, 1334957092752100409132, 1566365198635995978988, 1801452751402955781592, 2029966595320794439668, 2240353897304462193848, 2420609646335251593480, 2559320275988283588176, 2646791812246207696810, 2676118542978972739644, 2644036970936308845148, 2551425591643957182856, 2403354418943890067404, 2208653487832260558008, 1979045408073272278264, 1727958521630464742736, 1469189341596552030212, 1215604411161527170376, 978057923319151340728, 764655844340519788496, 580430565842543266504, 427417353874088245520, 305060580205223726864, 210835921361505594848, 140960183546144741182, 91071943593142473900, 56796799826096529620, 34150590308701283528, 19772322481956974532, 11008161481780603512, 5884917700519129288, 3016191418506637264, 1479594496462756340, 693434955498545848, 309881648709683160, 131760770157606224, 53181959591958024, 20324543852025936, 7333879739219600, 2490875091238112, 793548088258508, 236221241425176, 65418624260840, 16771945556496, 3958458557608, 854515874096, 167453394320, 29524775520, 4634116312, 639097008, 76185104, 7685024, 637360, 41696, 2016, 64, 1]

r = np.roots(coeff)

plt.plot(r.real, r.imag, '.')
```

### [image: something maybe]

I would suggest something more like the following (stolen and modified from [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2358/how-to-plot-the-mandelbrot-set/mandelbrot-set)). This sounds like something you've already tried. But try changing the max iterations to get something that can run relatively fast (30 was fast and had relatively high resolution for me).

```
MAX_ITER = 30

def mandelbrot(c):
    z = 0
    n = 0
    while abs(z) <= 2 and n < MAX_ITER:
        z = z*z + c
        n += 1
    return n
```

```
# Image size (pixels)
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 400

# Plot window
RE_START = -2
RE_END = 1
IM_START = -1
IM_END = 1

img = np.zeros((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
for x in range(0, WIDTH):
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT):
        # Convert pixel coordinate to complex number
        c = complex(RE_START + (x / WIDTH) * (RE_END - RE_START),
                    IM_START + (y / HEIGHT) * (IM_END - IM_START))
        # Compute the number of iterations
        m = mandelbrot(c)

        if m > MAX_ITER-1:
          img[x, y] = 1

plt.imshow(img.T, cmap='bone')
```

[image: output picture]